Cellular automaton to produce circles
Imagine forest fire without wind from single source. It will produce circle of fire. But how to get a good circle via cellula automata model?
So I am trying to produce circles with cellular automaton on rectangular grid.
Obviously spreading via horizontal / vertical boundaries will produce a square (rotated 45 degrees). Spreading via king moves will produce regular square.
I tried making diagonal moves only on sqrt(2) steps. This gives me octagon
Then I played with making diagonal moves randomly with probability 0.2 That gives much better result.

Any ideas on how to produce good circles or calculate exact probability for diagonal moves?
I want to model autowaves in excitable media (that can produce autowave spirals) so I cannot go with obvious solution - calculate distance from source point and activate cell if x^2+y^2 ~= t*v

Python code.

What exactly is the question?

@TravisWilse Rules for cellular automata that will produce circular wave activation from single point without explicit knowledge about source point.

@TravisWillse Imagine forest fire without wind. It will produce circle of fire. But how to get a good circle via cellula automata model?

Simplest way to do it is to make the state of a cell a bunch of floating point numbers and basically implement the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction (or similar excitable medium representing set of partial differential equations) as a numerical simulation of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction%E2%80%93diffusion_system - it will give you the smooth circular waves you desire.
